# How to retrieve signed user docs from docusign?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, restsharp, docusignapi

I have completed the setup of embedded signing using docusign for a C# MVC site. I would like to retrieve the signed docs from docusign in the form of a link - like click on link and access the docs(without having to sign in docusign) to see if the user has signed or not etc or download it as a pdf on my site. Is there a way to do this via a rest call may be ? I tried this REST call from the documentation - /restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/correct .. but it did not really get me what I wanted.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can easily retrieve (download) the envelope documents through the API.  One of the API Walkthroughs show code in how to do this in 6 different languages, and if you want the raw REST(ful) info you can check out [this page](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#Basic%20Scenarios/Retrieving%20Envelope%20and%20Documents.htm) from the API docs.

For the API Walkthroughs see #6 labeled "Get Document List & Download Docs":

http://iodocs.docusign.com/apiwalkthroughs

Comment: Thank you @Ergin. I was able to download the pdf successfuly